# Difference betwen 讲 的是 and 讲

Tags: grammar, learning

In this sentence:

> 这个电影 **讲 的是**一个人因为被追杀 , 躲 在 少林寺 里边学功夫, 然后为他爸爸 报仇的故事

I do not understand the structure in the bold part. Specifically, what is the difference between using just 讲 and using 讲 的是 as in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) 这个电影 讲 一个人 为他爸爸报仇 的 故事.

(b) 这个电影 讲的 (內容) 是 一个人为他爸爸报仇 的 故事.

From the grammar/structure point of view, (a) is an SVO structure. (b) is a "to-be" sentence. Since 这个电影 (or 这本书) is not a real person and cannot really talk (讲),  some people prefer the second structure which states the fact (是).

In practice, both are correct.

For example:

A: 他借我们的钱，可能不会还了。（He may not pay our money back.)

B: 你说，他借钱不还？（You mean, he does not pay us back?)

A: 我**说的是**，他可能没有能力还。(What I'm telling you is that he may not be able to pay it back.)

Answer (score 2):

讲的 = 描述的, described.

- 这个电影**讲的**是... = This movie **described** is ...

讲 - tell, talk, speak...